# DOMDocument->saveXML() taking too long

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

So, I've created a 34MB XML file.

When I try to get the output from `DOMDocument->saveXML()`, it takes 94 seconds to return.

I assume the code that generates this XML is irrelevant here, as the problem **is** on the saveXML() line:

```
$this->exportDOM = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$this->exportDOM->formatOutput = TRUE;
$this->exportDOM->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$this->exportDOM->loadXML('<export><produtos></produtos><fornecedores></fornecedores><transportadoras></transportadoras><clientes></clientes></export>');

[...]

$this->benchmark->mark('a');
$this->exportDOM->saveXML();
$this->benchmark->mark('b');
echo $this->benchmark->elapsed_time('a','b');
die;
```

This gives me `94.4581`.

What am I doing wrong? Do you guys know any performance-related issues with DOMDocument when generating the file?

If you need additional info, let me know. Thanks.

---

I tried removing `formatOutput`. It improves the perfomance by 33%.

Still taking too long. Any other tips?

Comment: I hope I'm wrong but handling large XML files (and, in the world of XML, I'd dare say that 34 MB qualifies as large) is a very resource intensive task when done with smart libraries like DOMDocument or SimpleXML. You can try with `formatOutput = FALSE` but, I that doesn't improve response, you may need to switch to an ugly but fast [pull parser](http://php.net/xmlwriter).

Comment: I *just* tried with `formatOutput = FALSE;`. It improves the perfomance by ~33%. Still taking too long, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that helped - although it isn't the perfect solution - was setting `$this->exportDOM->formatOutput = FALSE;`.

It improved the performance by ~33%.